# How to assign normal domain user as admin user for computer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm using Windows XP. How can I put a normal domain user account into admin group so that this normal user can administrate this normal computer?

Comment: Can you clarify this please?  What do you mean "normal"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to put a normal domain user account into admin group**

> - Right Click on My Computer
> - Then select Manage
> - Then Computer Management Dialog Box will pop up
> - In the left pane ,select Local Users and groups
> - In the right pane , open users
> - Find your domain user
> - Right Click on your Domain User and select properties
> - A properties Window will pop, select Tab 'Member of'
> - Now click on Add Button ,  another 'Select groups' window will pop up
> - Go to Advanced, Click on 'Find Now' button
> - Select Administrator and Click on OK
> - Click on OK where ever necessary
> - You are done